# Same subview shows repeatedly when custom tableView cell reused (Swift 4.1)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subview

I have a problem when I draw a set of CGRects in my custom tableView cell, they showed repeatedly when the cells get reused, which is not what I desired.

Here is the tableView(cellForRowAt indexPath:) function in my tableView controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.addBlock(item: itemArray[indexPath.row])

    cell.itemTitle.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].itemTitle

    return cell
}
```

And here is the function in my CustomTableViewCell class: (created with a xib file)

```
func addBlock(item: Item) {
    for i in 0 ..< item.numberOfBlocks {
        let block = UIView()
        block.frame = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(
                x: CGFloat(i) * 10,
                y: 0
            ),
            size: CGSize(
                width: 10,
                height: bounds.size.height
            )
        )
        block.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        self.addSubview(block)
    }
}
```

I think I draw every cell based on the numberOfBlock property in my itemArray Items, but when the cells are reused, the blocks won't redraw...
I have tried search here and elsewhere, but I couldn't find the answer (for a long time), I am new to swift, please bear with me...thank you very much.

Note: 
Item class includes 2 properties:
1. itemTitle: String, 
2. numberOfBlocks: Int

Comment: It looks like you are adding subviews ***every time*** you dequeue a cell. You need to either re-use them, or remove them before adding new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have this problem because `let block = UIView()` not removed from the cell on reuse. If it is, you can try this strategy:

1. Hold every `let block = UIView()` in you `CustomTableViewCell` class;
2. Implement [`prepareForReuse()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) method and remove all `block`s from superview.

This steps guarantee that reused cell doesn't have any block from previous state.

A bit of implementation:

```
final class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private var blocks: [UIView] = []

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        blocks.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        blocks = []
    }

    func addBlock(item: Item) {
        for ... {
            let block = UIView()
            ...
            blocks.append(block)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just figure it out 5 minutes ago..., I removed the blocks in the cellForRowAt function by casting my CGRects into a new class, and remove all subView in that class..., but you have enlightened me with new ways I haven't thought about, thank you